# Apply plugin in precompile script with Gradle and Kotlin

Tags: gradle, kotlin, plugins

I'm trying to apply `precompile` script `gradle.kts` file (`gradle.kts` script is put in `buildSrc/main/java`. everything work normally except that i can not add a plugin with version. for example my `test.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
  id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") version "1.1.1"
}
```

but always got the error

```
Invalid plugin request [id: 'io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt', version: '1.1.1']. Plugin requests from precompiled scripts must not include a version number. Please remove the version from the offending request and make sure the module containing the requested plugin 'io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt' is an implementation dependency of project ':buildSrc'.
```

And also I cannot the class to configure extension

For example, this normally configuration is not working

```
configure<DetektExtension>
```

How can we specify plugin version in `precompile` `script`? and how can we configure the plugin?

Comment: Please refrain from adding salutations ("Hi") and sign-offs ("thanks") to your posts. Technical writing is preferred here.

Answer (score 3):

Without being able to see your build structure and file tree I can only answer based on how I'm understanding your question. Based on the error message you are receiving, you should be declaring the plugin dependency in the project level build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") version "1.1.1"
}
```

Then in your buildSrc/build.gradle implement it like so:

```
plugins {
    `io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt`
}
```

Gradle has samples on GitHub, from which I drew this example, here:
https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/tree/master/samples/multi-kotlin-project-with-buildSrc

Comment: thanks use plugins {} in buildSrc work but is this the only option? can we use custom plugin or precompile script to configure extension? (some thing like put detekt {} inside these file?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh yes I believe if you follow the pattern in the docs here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:writing_a_simple_plugin

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For those who came here and looking for an answer, please notice that the format need to be 
plugins {
   " io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt"
}

Comment: Usually back ticks work. I edited my answer to add the missing back tick